# What's the preferred way to store environment/configuration variables in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

What's the best way to handle configuration for different environments in an Express app?

Should I place {development, production, testing}.json in /.config and load the appropriate one based on process.env.NODE_ENV? Something like...

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require('./config/' + env + ".json");
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use environment variables?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very clear. I'm using environment variables but specifically how do I easily load different values based on environment e.g. port 8080 in development but 3000 in production. Hope that's a little clearer...

Comment: I meant using env vars for those values, as 12 factor suggests: http://12factor.net/config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've normally done something like this:

File structure:

```
config/
  config.js
  env/
    development.js
    test.js
    production.js
```

And then inside the `config.js` file store universal config things, as well as loading the respective environment config:

```
// main config.js file

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// load the config file for the current environment
var config = require('./env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV);

// extend config with universal config data
config.someEnvAgnosticSetting = true;

// export config
module.exports = config;
```

This allows you to easily separate out environment specific configurations, while allowing any module requiring the config to only need to require the root config file.

For example, in your `server.js`file:

```
// require config, not worrying about what environment is being loaded
var config = require('./config/config');

// use config data
app.listen(config.port);
```

Edit: BTW, I didn't make this approach up - it's a really common one for node apps (or web apps in general, but it just so happens that in node you need to roll your own setup). Check out the [mean.js example app](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/tree/master/config) for a more in depth example using this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to also take a look to the [`env-dot-prop`](https://github.com/simonepri/env-dot-prop) package.

It allows you to set/get properties from `process.env` using a [`dot-path`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dot-prop).

Let's assume that your `process.env` contains the following:

```
process.env = {
  FOO_BAR: 'baz'
  'FOO_': '42'
}
```

Then you can manipulate the environment variables like that:

```
const envDotProp = require('env-dot-prop');

console.log(process.env);
//=> {FOO_BAR: 'baz', 'FOO_': '42'}

envDotProp.get('foo');
//=> {bar: 'baz', '': '42'}

envDotProp.get('foo.');
//=> '42'

envDotProp.get('foo.', {parse: true});
//=> 42

envDotProp.set('baz.foo', 'bar');
envDotProp.get('', {parse: true});
//=> {foo: {bar: 'baz', '': 42}, baz: {foo: 'bar'}}

console.log(process.env);
//=> {FOO_BAR: 'baz', 'FOO_': '42', BAZ_FOO: 'bar'}

envDotProp.delete('foo');
envDotProp.get('');
//=> {baz: {foo: 'bar'}}

console.log(process.env);
//=> {BAZ_FOO: 'bar'}
```

This helps you to parse the environment variables and use them as a config object in your app.
It also helps you implement a [12-factor configuration](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: I think the answer would be better understood without emojis, they're super distracting